# Rails - searching and configuration of Solr

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, solr, rubygems, sunspot-solr

I use for searching a content in my app **Solr**. What I don't like is, that everytime, when I restart computer, I have to manually start **Solr** and then, when is in the app a new content, I have to reindex that, because in other hand Solr wouldn't find the new data.

This is not very comfortable, how looks the work with Solr on the server, eg. on Heroku? Do I have there starting Solr all the time or do I have there reindex data over and over again, as on my localhost I do?

Eventually, exist better solution for searching except **Solr**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the included server, right?

You can choose to [deploy it in Tomcat](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrTomcat). You just have to copy your files to Tomcat and register your Solr application in Tomcat configuration. Tomcat is run as a service. Or, you can use a script to start Jetty on startup.

And a professional Solr service **tries to** keep your Solr application alive and your data safe against any cause such as a crashed software, failed server or even a datacenter that went down.

Check what Heroku (or other hosted Solr solutions) promises you in their terms. They would do a much better job than an individual (no restarting Solr instances frequently!).

---

When you add something to Solr, it is persisted to disk. When commited, it is available to search. If a document changes, you reindex it to reflect the new changes.

When you restart Solr, the **same persisted data** is available. What is your exact trouble?

There is the DIH (Direct Import Handler) if you want to automatically index from a DB.

Answer (score 0):

I'm happy with Solr so far.
As far as starting Solr instance after restarting your computer, you can write a bash script that would do it for you, or declare an alias that would start your Solr and your app server.

As far as re-indexing. New and updated records should be re-indexed automatically, unless manipulate your data from the console.

For the alternate solutions check out [Thinking Sphinx](http://freelancing-god.github.com/ts/en/)